# select retornar resultados sem repetir resposta

Tags: sql, distinct

Tenho a seguinte query

```
   SELECT 
    (SUM(DISTINCT result)/COUNT(*))as total,
    uf FROM users WHERE result > 0 and result IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY uf ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Quero selecionar todos os 5 resultados  sem repetir os valores de total  estou utilizando o distinct mais mesmo assim esta retornando total repetido

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que deseja. Se o total for igual, mesmo que diferentes UF, você deseja listar apenas um? Faz sentido?

Comment: eu tenho uma tabela chamada user nela tenho o result(resultado que cada pessoa tem) nesta mesma tabela tenho o estado que a pessoa e  eu quero listar  o 5 maiores resultados de toda tabela  de forma que nao se repita valor por exemplo sp e mg tem  total  igual a 100  so vou pegar uma deles que  e sp e outro nao  ....

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está usando?

Comment: estou usando mysql

Comment: Mas você está utilizando o DISTINCT sobre o campo result e não sobre o total. Além disso na soma você só considera valores distintos mas na quantidade (COUNT) considera todos os valores.

Comment: OK entendi entao tenho q colocar no total ,mas como ficaria

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer usar `WITH QUERIES` para processar os dados até chegar no resultado que vocês precisa.

Tente usar este comando SQL e depois diga se funcionou.

```sql
WITH 
-- Lista os Totais por UF
query_totais AS 
(
   SELECT 
      SUM(result)/COUNT(*) AS total
      , uf
   FROM users 
   WHERE result > 0 and result IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY uf 
),
-- Adiciona na query anterior a coluna "rownum",
-- que será como se fosse a classificação do registro.
-- Se houver o mesmo total em duas UFs, a primeira terá valor "1" e a segunda terá valor "2"
query_totais_com_rownum AS 
(
   SELECT 
      total
      , uf
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY total ORDER BY total DESC, uf) AS rownum
   FROM query_totais
)
-- Resultado Final
SELECT 
   total
   , uf
FROM query_totais_com_rownum
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: OLa  tambem nao esta dando certo